# Q: An alternative way to update a shared CSV file using a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I use a shared CSV file to store shared values. I read and write to the file using the Python dictionary module. The updates, reading and writings happen a lot of times, from different methods, threads and processes. Due to safety reasons the values have to be saved right away.

At the moment every time I would like to modify an entry, I read the file into a dictionary, update the `[key,value]` and then write back to the file. The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5 python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# read the temp file as dictionary
with open('/home/pi/tempExchange.csv','rt') as tempRead:
    tempReader = csv.reader(tempRead)
    tempDict = dict(tempReader)
                        
tempDict["k0"] = 000
tempDict["k1"] = 100
tempDict["k2"] = 200
tempDict["k3"] = 300

with open("/home/pi/tempExchange.csv", "wt") as tempWrite:
    w = csv.writer(tempWrite)
    w.writerows(sorted(tempDict.items()))
```

Is there an alternative, a more pythonic way to update a CSV file without constantly opening and closing the file?

Comment: Keep the data in memory, and only write it when the processing is finished ?

Comment: My apologies @hansolo. The CSV file is accessed from multiple files too and I do not know how keeping the data in memory would simplify the things. Also the main script runs on a RPi machine and the values have to be stored right after being modified for safety reasons.